# Using multiple data sources (Micronaut) javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException

Tags: java, micronaut

I am trying to use multiple database connections with micronaut (1.2.0) no injection method worked for me this is my configuration:

application.yml

```
datasources:
  default:
    url: ${JDBC_URL:`jdbc:mysql://localhost/cossine?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC`}
    username: ${JDBC_USER:******}
    password: ${JDBC_PASSWORD:*****}
    driverClassName: ${JDBC_DRIVER:com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver}
  keycloak:
    url: ${JDBC_KYC_URL:`jdbc:mysql://localhost/keycloak?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC`}
    username: ${JDBC_KYC_USER:******}
    password: ${JDBC_KYC_PASSWORD:*******}
    driverClassName: ${JDBC_DRIVER:com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver}
jpa:
  default:
    packages-to-scan:
      - 'com.acmain.domain'
    properties:
      hibernate:
        hbm2ddl:
          auto: none
        show_sql: false
  keycloak:
    packages-to-scan:
      - 'com.acmain.kdomain'
    properties:
      hibernate:
        hbm2ddl:
          auto: none
        show_sql: true
```

When I use the default configuration it works without problems, but when using the second  like this :

```
 private final EntityManager entityManager;

    public UserEntityImpl(@CurrentSession(value = "keycloak") EntityManager em) {
        this.entityManager = em;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public UsersResponse findAll(@NotNull SortingAndOrderArguments args) {
        List<UserEntity> users;
        StringBuilder qlString = new StringBuilder("SELECT g FROM UserEntity as g");
...........................
```

one I get the following error:

```
Hibernate: select count(userentity0_.id) as col_0_0_ from user_entity userentity0_
Hibernate: select userentity0_.id as id1_0_, userentity0_.email as email2_0_, userentity0_.enabled as enabled3_0_, userentity0_.first_name as first_na4_0_, userentity0_.last_name as last_nam5_0_, userentity0_.realm_id as realm_id6_0_ from user_entity userentity0_ order by userentity0_.email asc limit ?
14:10:59.822 [RxCachedThreadScheduler-1] ERROR i.m.h.s.netty.RoutingInBoundHandler - Unexpected error occurred: no transaction is in progress
javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.checkTransactionNeededForUpdateOperation(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:398)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.checkTransactionNeededForUpdateOperation(SessionImpl.java:3617)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1473)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1469)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SessionFactoryUtils.flush(SessionFactoryUtils.java:147)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SpringSessionSynchronization.beforeCommit(SpringSessionSynchronization.java:95)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationUtils.triggerBeforeCommit(TransactionSynchronizationUtils.java:96)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.triggerBeforeCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:922)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:730)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:714)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:534)
    at io.micronaut.spring.tx.annotation.TransactionInterceptor.intercept(TransactionInterceptor.java:88)
    at io.micronaut.aop.MethodInterceptor.intercept(MethodInterceptor.java:40)
    at io.micronaut.aop.chain.InterceptorChain.proceed(InterceptorChain.java:150)
    at io.micronaut.validation.ValidatingInterceptor.intercept(ValidatingInterceptor.java:157)
    at io.micronaut.aop.MethodInterceptor.intercept(MethodInterceptor.java:40)
    at io.micronaut.aop.chain.InterceptorChain.proceed(InterceptorChain.java:150)
    at com.acmain.repository.$UserEntityImplDefinition$Intercepted.findAll(Unknown Source)
    at com.acmain.service.UserService.getAllUsers(UserService.java:181)
    at com.acmain.controller.UserController.getUsers(UserController.java:48)
    at com.acmain.controller.$UserControllerDefinition$Intercepted.$$access2(Unknown Source)
    at com.acmain.controller.$UserControllerDefinition$Intercepted$$proxy2.invokeInternal(Unknown Source)
    at io.micronaut.context.AbstractExecutableMethod.invoke(AbstractExecutableMethod.java:144)
    at io.micronaut.aop.chain.InterceptorChain.lambda$new$1(InterceptorChain.java:93)
    at io.micronaut.aop.chain.InterceptorChain.proceed(InterceptorChain.java:150)
    at io.micronaut.validation.ValidatingInterceptor.intercept(ValidatingInterceptor.java:157)
    at io.micronaut.aop.MethodInterceptor.intercept(MethodInterceptor.java:40)
    at io.micronaut.aop.chain.InterceptorChain.proceed(InterceptorChain.java:150)
    at com.acmain.controller.$UserControllerDefinition$Intercepted.getUsers(Unknown Source)
    at com.acmain.controller.$$UserControllerDefinition$InterceptedDefinition$$exec3.invokeInternal(Unknown Source)
    at io.micronaut.context.AbstractExecutableMethod.invoke(AbstractExecutableMethod.java:144)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext$BeanExecutionHandle.invoke(DefaultBeanContext.java:2792)
    at io.micronaut.web.router.AbstractRouteMatch.execute(AbstractRouteMatch.java:294)
    at io.micronaut.web.router.RouteMatch.execute(RouteMatch.java:122)
    at io.micronaut.http.server.netty.RoutingInBoundHandler.lambda$buildResultEmitter$19(RoutingInBoundHandler.java:1408)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableCreate.subscribeActual(FlowableCreate.java:71)
    at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14918)
    at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14865)
    at io.micronaut.reactive.rxjava2.RxInstrumentedFlowable.subscribeActual(RxInstrumentedFlowable.java:68)
    at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14918)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableMap.subscribeActual(FlowableMap.java:37)
    at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14918)
    at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14865)
    at io.micronaut.reactive.rxjava2.RxInstrumentedFlowable.subscribeActual(RxInstrumentedFlowable.java:68)
    at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14918)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableSwitchIfEmpty.subscribeActual(FlowableSwitchIfEmpty.java:32)
    at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14918)
    at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14865)
    at io.micronaut.reactive.rxjava2.RxInstrumentedFlowable.subscribeActual(RxInstrumentedFlowable.java:68)
    at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14918)
    at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14868)
    at io.micronaut.http.context.ServerRequestTracingPublisher.lambda$subscribe$0(ServerRequestTracingPublisher.java:52)
    at io.micronaut.http.context.ServerRequestContext.with(ServerRequestContext.java:52)
    at io.micronaut.http.context.ServerRequestTracingPublisher.subscribe(ServerRequestTracingPublisher.java:52)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFromPublisher.subscribeActual(FlowableFromPublisher.java:29)
    at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14918)
    at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14865)
    at io.micronaut.reactive.rxjava2.RxInstrumentedFlowable.subscribeActual(RxInstrumentedFlowable.java:68)
    at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14918)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableSwitchMap.subscribeActual(FlowableSwitchMap.java:49)
    at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14918)
    at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14865)
    at io.micronaut.reactive.rxjava2.RxInstrumentedFlowable.subscribeActual(RxInstrumentedFlowable.java:68)
    at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14918)
    at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14865)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableSwitchMap$SwitchMapSubscriber.onNext(FlowableSwitchMap.java:129)
    at io.micronaut.reactive.rxjava2.InstrumentedSubscriber.lambda$onNext$0(InstrumentedSubscriber.java:80)
    at io.micronaut.reactive.rxjava2.InstrumentedSubscriber.onNext(InstrumentedSubscriber.java:84)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableSubscribeOn$SubscribeOnSubscriber.onNext(FlowableSubscribeOn.java:97)
    at io.micronaut.reactive.rxjava2.InstrumentedSubscriber.lambda$onNext$0(InstrumentedSubscriber.java:80)
    at io.micronaut.reactive.rxjava2.InstrumentedSubscriber.onNext(InstrumentedSubscriber.java:84)
    at io.reactivex.internal.subscriptions.DeferredScalarSubscription.complete(DeferredScalarSubscription.java:132)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFromCallable.subscribeActual(FlowableFromCallable.java:50)
    at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14918)
    at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14865)
    at io.micronaut.reactive.rxjava2.RxInstrumentedCallableFlowable.subscribeActual(RxInstrumentedCallableFlowable.java:65)
    at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14918)
    at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14865)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableSubscribeOn$SubscribeOnSubscriber.run(FlowableSubscribeOn.java:82)
    at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.run(ScheduledRunnable.java:66)
    at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.call(ScheduledRunnable.java:57)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

what am I missing?

also tried

```
 @PersistenceContext(name = "keycloak")
    private final EntityManager entityManager;
```

Comment: Perhaps you need to specify a transaction manager per database. Sorry, not familiar with micronaut but seems similar to spring boot.

Comment: Solved , work just adding  @Transactional("keycloak")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well just need to add

```
  @Transactional("keycloak")
```

to the method

Is not documented here https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-sql/latest/guide/#hibernate

But found the uses here

https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-sql/blob/master/hibernate-jpa/src/test/groovy/io/micronaut/configuration/hibernate/jpa/MultipleDataSourceJpaSetupSpec.groovy

Comment: What if we are using javax.transaction.transactional

Comment: I think you meant `@TransactionalAdvice`? There is no usage of `@Transactional` in the linked spec, and the annotation does not support defining datasources that way regardless. This is not the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone lands here looking for how to do this when not using Hibernate, this should do it.

```java
@Transactional
@TransactionalAdvice("my-datasource") // if you have more than one datasource
public Thing saveThing(Thing thing) {
    repo.save(thing);
    
}
```

Comment: ... does this mean that you cannot handle multiple datasources in the same method? I'm using Jdbi and I really wish I could use 2 different jdbi instances for different DBs in the same Transactional method... I know that there might still be issues with transaction commits at the end, but it's better than having to split the code into N-commits per DB plus manually handle every possible point of rollback... if the commit only happened at the end I'd only have to handle 1 place where the two transactions might be out of sync instead of 2*N...

Answer (score 1):

The [Micronaut docs](https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-data/3.4.1/guide/index.html#dbcRepositories) are fairly clear about this:

> In a multiple datasource scenario, the @Repository and
> @TransactionalAdvice annotations can be used to specify the datasource
> configuration to use. By default Micronaut Data will look for the
> default datasource.
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> @Repository("inventoryDataSource") 
> @JdbcRepository(dialect = Dialect.ORACLE) 
> @TransactionalAdvice("inventoryDataSource") 
> public interface PhoneRepository extends CrudRepository<Phone, Integer> {
>     Optional<Phone> findByAssetId(@NotNull Integer assetId);
> }
> ```